# PRAW - searching for NSFW submissions

Tags: python, praw

I'm noticing that nsfw posts are not showing up when using the search method on a subreddit.

`for submission in self.reddit.subreddit('nsfw_subreddit').search('a'):
            print(submission.title)`

Nothing is printed out. However when i use `new()` or `hot()` it seems like nsfw subreddits are being shown. Is there any parameter I need to pass in to the `search()` method that I'm currently missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have "I am over eighteen years old and willing to view adult content" checked in [Reddit preferences](https://www.reddit.com/prefs), changing your search to the following will enable NSFW results:

```
for submission in self.reddit.subreddit('nsfw_subreddit').search('a', params={'include_over_18': 'on'}):
    print(submission.title)
```